# Google Analytics (asynchronous) on a large site with pages containing iframes

Tags: iframe, asynchronous, google-analytics, tracking

I want to track a large website as a whole with several 'normal'pages and several pages containing i-frames. The framed pages' sources are at different domains.

How would I go about in making it work in such a way that all the pages (including the i-framed pages) are tracked in the correct way, even allowing in-page analytics on them?

Here's how far I got: Your comments, please?

1 normal pages should have the normal tracking code.

2 The pages containing i-frames AND the framed pages inside the i-frame should have the adjusted multi-domain tracking code:

```
 var _gaq = _gaq || [];

  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-xx']);

  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.THIS_IS_THE_SUBPAGE_URL_CONTAINING_I-FRAME']);

  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  _gaq.push(function() {

  var pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();

  var iframe = document.getElementById('THIS_IS_THE_I-FRAME_ID');

  iframe.src = pageTracker._getLinkerUrl('THIS_IS_THE_FRAMED_PAGE_URL');
});

  (function(){
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

  })();
```

**Question:**
Am I going about this in the right way? Do the frames need some sort of Javascript cookie transfer? What about P3P policy, does this need to be added?